# Error in service account authority certificate in Openshift

Tags: jenkins, service, openshift, service-accounts

Currently, I am trying to deploy application using Jenkins pipeline to OpenShift, but I am receiving an error.

> ERROR: OpenShift Client exited with status code 1, command: [Oc, --server=172.17.54.97:9080, --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/#serviceaccount/ca.crt, --namespace=deployment-center-app, --token=XXXXX, get, builds, -l openshift.io/build-config.name=ci-sample-9080, -w, -o=name], stderr: error: the server doesn't have a resource type "build"

Is this something related to security token?